# Why does my recyclerview adapter not work? / Why is the class not running?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have been trying to get the adapter for my RecyclerView to work, but I cannot get anything to display upon the cards, and also, the CycleTrails class does not run as the Logcat does not show any of the logs setup through the class... Before I setup the Adapter, everything worked fine, I could get all of the values from my CycleTrails class. But now, things are messed up and I cannot figure out why.

MainActivity.java (the onCreate part/only thing that I added with the adapter)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rvItem = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItem);
    rvItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
    ArrayList<Trails> finalData = getTrails();
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, finalData);
    rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

CycleTrails.java

```
public class CycleTrails extends MainActivity {

public static double LAT_MAX = myLatitude + (0.01 * 200);
public static double LAT_MIN = myLatitude - (0.01 * 200);
public static double LON_MAX = myLongitude + (0.01 * 200);
public static double LON_MIN = myLongitude - (0.01 * 200);

public static ArrayList<Trails> getTrails() {
    Log.d("trails", "Cycle trails running");
    ArrayList<Trails> trailList = new ArrayList<>();
    Trails t1 = new Trails(51.71, -3.36, "Bike Park Wales", "", "", "");
    Trails t2 = new Trails(51.66, -3.35, "Mountain Ash", "", "", "");
    Trails t3 = new Trails(50.50, -4.17, "FlyUp Downhill", "", "", "");
    trailList.add(t1);
    trailList.add(t2);
    trailList.add(t3);


    final ArrayList<Trails> localTrails = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Trails trail : trailList) {
        Log.d("List running", "Local trail list");
        if (trail.lat > LAT_MIN && trail.lat < LAT_MAX && trail.lon > LON_MIN && trail.lon < LON_MAX) {
            localTrails.add(trail);
            Log.d("Calc", "Run code");


            final RequestBuilder weather = new RequestBuilder();

            final Request request = new Request();
            request.setLat(String.valueOf(trail.lat));
            Log.d("Lat used", String.valueOf(trail.lat));
            Log.d("Actual Lat", request.getLat());
            request.setLng(String.valueOf(trail.lon));
            Log.d("Lon used", String.valueOf(trail.lon));
            request.setUnits(Request.Units.UK);
            request.setLanguage(Request.Language.ENGLISH);
            request.addExcludeBlock(Request.Block.CURRENTLY);
            request.removeExcludeBlock(Request.Block.CURRENTLY);


            weather.getWeather(request, new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(WeatherResponse weatherResponse, Response response) {
                    Log.d("Weather", "We have weather!");
                    Log.d("Location", weatherResponse.getTimezone());
                    trail.temp = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.getCurrently().getTemperature());
                    Log.d("Temperature", trail.temp);
                    trail.weather = weatherResponse.getCurrently().getIcon();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Log.d("Error while calling: ", "Weather");
                }


            });
        } else {
            Log.d("Too far", "Trails too far" + trail.name);
        }
    }
    return localTrails;
}

}
```

Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
public ArrayList <Trails> finalData;

public Adapter (Context context, ArrayList<Trails> finalData) {
    Log.d("Hello", "Adapter");
    this.context = context;
    this.finalData = finalData;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    Log.d("Hello", "2");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.trail_card, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Trails trails = finalData.get(position);
    Log.d("Hello", "3");
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("http://www.wigglestatic.com/product-media/5360108808/Wiggle-Road-Bike-Road-Bikes-Black-1WGMY16R7048UK0001-6.jpg?w=2000&h=2000&a=7")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.cycle)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(holder.locationImage);
    holder.locationText.setText(trails.name);
    Log.d("Location", trails.name);
    holder.temperatureText.setText(trails.temp);
    Log.d("Temperature", trails.temp);
    holder.weatherText.setText(trails.weather);
    holder.conditionsText.setText(trails.conditions);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("Hello", "4");
    if(finalData != null) {
        Log.d("Hello", "5");
        return finalData.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView cardView;
    public ImageView locationImage;
    public TextView locationText;
    public TextView temperatureText;
    public TextView weatherText;
    public TextView conditionsText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        locationImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationImage);
        locationText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationText);
        temperatureText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.temperatureText);
        weatherText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
        conditionsText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.conditionsText);
    }
}
}
```

Trails.java

```
public class Trails {
public String name;
public double lat;   // Object fields
public double lon;
public String temp;
public String weather;
public static String conditions;


Trails(double lat, double lon, String name, String temp, String weather, String conditions){ // construcor
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.name = name;
    this.temp = temp;
    this.weather = weather;
    this.conditions = conditions;
}
}
```

This is the logcat for the whole app running

```
03-16 10:32:48.877 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Lat: 52.1981981981982
03-16 10:32:48.877 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Lon: -2.2341297062250933
03-16 10:33:19.859 20535-20542/com.example.android.cycleuk W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.141ms
03-16 10:33:19.956 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Hello: Adapter
03-16 10:33:20.023 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Hello: 4
03-16 10:33:20.023 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Hello: 4
03-16 10:33:20.069 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Lat: 52.1981981981982
03-16 10:33:20.069 20535-20535/com.example.android.cycleuk D/Lon: -2.2341297062250933
```

Comment: did you bind the adapter with Recycleview?

Comment: check `finalData` is null or not.

Comment: @JdPrajapati yep I think so, I bind it in the MainActivity right?

Comment: show the code where you binding the recycler view inside the acitivity

Comment: @aksacha it doesn't return because that whole class where it gets it's data from does not run at all and I don't know why

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir added the possible binding section you are talking about... If it is not showing above, then I don't think I have binded correctly

Answer (score 1):

Bind your adapter with recycleview..

```
ArrayList<Trails> finalData = getTrails();
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, finalData);
rvItem.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Ahh okay, where should I put this?

Comment: see first line...put as it is in your oncreate

Comment: This will not work because  ```getTrails()``` isn't a synchronous call

Comment: Ahh, I  just realised I missed out two lines from the original post, I already had this in the onCreate and it doesn't work

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your Adapter class slightly.First
you have to add Adapter to your recyclerView.Please be sure that recyclerView initialised with layout manger and not null.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here our **Adapter** class implementation.You have to create your List inside Adapter class.

```
public class Adapter {

ArrayList<Trails> finalData;
Context context;

public Adapter(Context context){
     this.context = context;
     finalData = new ArrayList<>();
}

.....

....

public void addItem(Trails data){
    finalData.add(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Note this method is important because it will let adapter know size of list changed and render the list
}

}
```

In your fragment or Activity class add that method

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);

/// here your methods what ever you want

dataList = getTrails();
for(Trails trails: dataList){
    adapter.addItem(trails);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Cheerd buddy! But implementing your fix does not help. notifyItemDataSetChanged(); is never declared as a method beforehand? Also, was dataList supposed to be finalData??

Comment: Sorry it has to be notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: No sadly :/ I have instead changed the way the ArrayList is made and so far it's working well :) Cheers for your time though!

Comment: Hey bro can you check new one. That should work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
I think your getTrails method always return size 0 list that why you never get anything in recyclerview. All code is working fine . just check your code that you get any data in your list before setting it into recyclerview.



public static ArrayList<Trails> getTrails() {
    Log.d("trails", "Cycle trails running");
    ArrayList<Trails> trailList = new ArrayList<>();
    Trails t1 = new Trails(51.71, -3.36, "Bike Park Wales", "", "", "");
    Trails t2 = new Trails(51.66, -3.35, "Mountain Ash", "", "", "");
    Trails t3 = new Trails(50.50, -4.17, "FlyUp Downhill", "", "", "");
    trailList.add(t1);
    trailList.add(t2);
    trailList.add(t3);


    final ArrayList<Trails> localTrails = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Trails trail : trailList) {
        Log.d("List running", "Local trail list");
        if (trail.lat > LAT_MIN && trail.lat < LAT_MAX && trail.lon > LON_MIN && trail.lon < LON_MAX) {
            localTrails.add(trail);
            Log.d("Calc", "Run code");


            final RequestBuilder weather = new RequestBuilder();

            final Request request = new Request();
            request.setLat(String.valueOf(trail.lat));
            Log.d("Lat used", String.valueOf(trail.lat));
            Log.d("Actual Lat", request.getLat());
            request.setLng(String.valueOf(trail.lon));
            Log.d("Lon used", String.valueOf(trail.lon));
            request.setUnits(Request.Units.UK);
            request.setLanguage(Request.Language.ENGLISH);
            request.addExcludeBlock(Request.Block.CURRENTLY);
            request.removeExcludeBlock(Request.Block.CURRENTLY);


            weather.getWeather(request, new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(WeatherResponse weatherResponse, Response response) {
                    Log.d("Weather", "We have weather!");
                    Log.d("Location", weatherResponse.getTimezone());
                    trail.temp = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.getCurrently().getTemperature());
                    Log.d("Temperature", trail.temp);
                    trail.weather = weatherResponse.getCurrently().getIcon();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Log.d("Error while calling: ", "Weather");
                }


            });
        } else {
            Log.d("Too far", "Trails too far" + trail.name);
        }
    }
    return localTrails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `weather.getWeather()` is not synchronous right?, this may cause your `localTrails` is always empty. And maybe you can try to put this code `localTrails.add(trail)` inside `success` method of your synchronous call.

Comment: Thank you, but the whole CycleTrails class does not run, so it does not even get to the success method of the synchronous call